# Как получить список запущеных приложений?

Tags: c#

Как получить список запущеных приложений?

```
foreach(var item in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcess())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ProcessName);
}
```

Выводит название запущеных процессов, а приложения?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял то вместо

```
Console.WriteLine(item.ProcessName);
```

Попробуй

```
if (item.MainWindowTitle != String.Empty)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.MainWindowTitle);
}
```

Comment: Оно то вроде и правильно, обьясню суть задачи: пишу диспетчер задач и вроде как все хорошо но, в процесах запущеніе такие как :conhost.exe, csrss.exe, winlogon.exe и т.д. вот как получить к ним доступ чтобы отображалось? Кто стыкался?

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь Win32 API:

```
using System.Management;

ManagementObjectSearcher Processes = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
foreach (ManagementObject Process in Processes.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(Process["Name"]);
}
```

Comment: Не забудьте что для использования класса ManagementObjectSearcher и самого  using System.Management в проект необходимо добавить сборку System.Management. В обозревателе решений : Проект-ссылки-ПКМ - добавить ссылку.